# How to send CTRL+Z keyEvent in java using Robot class

Tags: java

I am using Java Robot class to send keyevents. I tried `robot.keyPress()` function. But I could not figure out how to send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> keyEvent.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Z)
// CTRL+Z is now pressed (receiving application should see a "key down" event.)
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Z)
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
// CTRL+Z is now released (receiving application should now see a "key up" event - as well as a "key pressed" event).
```