# Copying a number from a window into a java program

Tags: java, io

I need to create a program that copies numbers from a window to a java file. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx3ba.png)
Since the numbers are not in a web browser, I can't scan a regular website for the data. I can, however, click on the number and press Ctrl + C to copy them. I basically need something that reads some given coordinates on my screen or something that can click on the numbers and copy and paste them into a text file.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You could JNI/JNA to do it, but it's not a simple process at the best of times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `java.awt.Robot` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) can be used to do the clicking and key pressing. [The `java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html) can be used to read the clipboard. Needed imports:

```java
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
```

Example code (note that `AWTException`, `UnsupportedFlavorException`, and `IOException` must be handled, perhaps by `throws Throwable` in the method header):

```java
// Things that need to be set up only once.
final Robot robot = new Robot();
final Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

// If you need a loop, start it here.
for (;;) {
    // Click at (x, y).
    robot.mouseMove(x, y);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    robot.delay(100);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    robot.delay(100);

    // Press Ctrl+C.
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.delay(100);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.delay(100);

    // Read clipboard.
    final String clipboardContents = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);

    // Work with clipboard contents.
    System.out.println(clipboardContents);
}
```

As far as putting the copied data into a text file, how you want to do that is up to you:

- You can modify the above to strip out the parts dealing with the clipboard contents and simply use the `Robot` to click on a different window and press Ctrl+V.
- You can modify the above to open a text file, write the clipboard contents to it, and save it.

---

Credit to:

- Kedar Mhaswade's answer to this question points to [an answer to "Get readable text only from clipboard"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7106086/7208029)
- [Answer to "how to send CTRL+Z keyEvent in java using Robot class"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9047727/7208029)

Answer (score 0):

Since (presumably) you can use `Ctrl+C` to copy the text, you can use the system clipboard. You could use the instructions in this [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105778/get-readable-text-only-from-clipboard) to read the system clipboard.

By relying on the system clipboard, you can work around the problem of reading a certain portion of the screen and do some character recognition.

Comment: Wow @Chai Thank you very much, works perfectly well.

Comment: Hey downvoter! Can you please explain why you did that? My answer was given credit by the accepted answer and I get a downvote? WHY?