# How To Simulate Key Presses Only To Selenium Browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, keyboard, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing my first program and this is my first time here, I'm sorry if I'm not explaining something properly.

I want to use one extension the extension's shortcut is **CTRL+SHIFT+A**.

How can I simulate those clicks **only** to the Selenium Browser and not to the whole PC or the Element on the page (I want to be able to run the program in the background).

I've tried
`driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a' + Keys.SHIFT)`
But I guess that doesn't work because it simulates keyboard presses to the body of the page and not to the browser, so the extension can't recognize it.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Selenium sends its input through regular keyboard and mouse events.

Comment: @Chris Thank you!, that's quite unfortunate

Comment: You can try with Robot class after launching browser with selenium. Here is an example to use Robot class.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047710/how-to-send-ctrlz-keyevent-in-java-using-robot-class